# MongoDB is missing from the Strapi database client

Tags: mongodb, strapi, headless-cms

Why MongoDB is not listed in the create-strapi-app installation process?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the release of Strapi v4, MongoDB is not supported natively anymore and no connector is available. Refer to this: https://strapi.io/blog/mongo-db-support-in-strapi-past-present-and-future